# Changing existing Hotmail email address to a different one

Tags: email, hotmail

I [read](http://www.careerealism.com/resume-avoid-age-discrimination-ways/) that revealing your age in your email address isn't in your favor when you're job hunting. Is it possible to change from one email address to another WITHOUT opening a new account and deleting the old one (i.e. johndoe1984@hotmail.com to john.doe@hotmail.com)?
I was researching, but I couldn't find any information about it.

Comment: Don't think so, but you could make an alias within Hotmail, that way, you will have your old email and a new email, but to access them, you have to login with your old email...

Comment: I guess delete it is.

Comment: Is there something wrong with aliases? I might be able to think of an alternative...

Comment: I love simplicity, and I don't use the old email anyway. Your advice is helpful, but I'll delete it anyway.

Comment: I think you should hold off deleting it... Someone may know a way...

Comment: Actually, look at the note here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows/outlook/add-alias-account (in the centre of the page...). You can make an alias, and delete the old one after setting the new one as your primary one. Is this something that you may like?

Comment: Yeah, makes more sense than deleting it. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want me to add an answer from that website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your current Hotmail account, you can make an **alias** and set this alias as your 'primary alias':

> If you want a new name for your account, you can add an alias, make the new alias primary, then remove the original alias.
>   <sub><sub><sub><sub>[Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows/outlook/add-alias-account)</sub></sub></sub></sub>

a) To add (or remove) the alias:

Go to www.outlook.com, login. Click your username at the top right, click "Account Settings". Click Overview > Add or Change aliases > Add alias (or remove). Make an account email

b) To set the new alias as your primary one:

Go to http://account.live.com. Click account aliases. Click "Make Primary" under your new alias.

c) To remove the original email address, go to step a).

**NOTE: THIS WILL REMOVE ALL YOUR EMAILS IN YOUR OLD EMAIL AND NOBODY WILL BE ABLE TO CONTACT YOU UNTIL THEY KNOW YOUR NEW EMAIL ADDRESS!!**

Answer (score 0):

Don’t delete.  Instead, create a new one and forward your emails to the old one (or vice versa).

Keep both addresses without having to make your current contacts update their address books.

Otherwise, the *alias* method mentioned makes sense, but I wouldn’t want my emails deleted.